# Equation of a circle problem with y-intercepts given

Tags: integration, geometry, circles, tangent-line

given the $y$-intercepts $-18$ and $-8$, tangent to the $x-$axis. The answer is

> $(x-12)^2+(y+13)^2=169$.

I just don't get it how to get the answer. The prof just gave the answer to it.

Comment: You means tangent to x-axis? If you draw a picture, you can understand it easily.

Comment: tangent to x axis sorry for that. I tried getting both of their midpoint and don't know what to do next

Comment: So, the circle's center is on the perpendicular bisector of the segment $((0, -18), (0, -8))$. And its radius is equal to the center distance from x-axis, or its x-coordinate.

Comment: so should I get the perpendicular bisector of the two points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The center $C$ is a point on the perpendicular bisector of the two $y$ intercepts that is the line $y=-13$, so $C=(\alpha,-13)$. Since the circle is tangent to the $x$ axis , its radius have to be $r=13$.  This means that the distance from  one  $y$ intercept, e.g $(0,-8)$ is such that:
$$
(0-\alpha)^2+(-8+13)^2=r^2= 169
$$

solve this for $\alpha$ and you have two circle.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what we do first: the line joining $(0,-18)$ and $(0,-8)$ forms a chord of the circle. Now, the perpendicular bisector of this chord is parallel to the x-axis, and has y-coordinate as $-13$. Hence because the perpendicular bisector of every chord passes through the center, the center has y-coordinate $13$.

Now, if the center has coordinates $(x,-13)$, then note that there is a right angled triangle, namely $(x,-13), (0,-13),(0,-18)$. Now, using the Pythagoras theorem, we get $x=\pm 12$.

Thus, we have two circles, one of center $(12,-13)$ and one of center $(-12,-13)$. Both have radius $13$, since  they touch the x-axis.

Comment: should the center would be positive or negative 12 in x position in the point?

Comment: Any one of them works. Both circles are tangent to the x-axis, and pass through $(0,-8)$ and $(0,-18)$.

Comment: Radius $13$, right?

Comment: @DavidK Correct, the radius is $13$, since we have to compare the y-coordinates. I will make the change.

Comment: I knew you knew that. I figured it was just a typographic error. That's why I already upvoted the answer yesterday. :-)

Comment: @DavidK Thank you. However it's good to point it out because people who encounter a similar problem may come and read this post and complain about the errors in the answer. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The problem seems to have two solutions:

[image]